# Динамическое изменение menu Android

Tags: android, menu

У в приложении есть DrawerLayout. Макет главной активности содержит DrawerLayout в корне. И дочерние элементы include и navigationView. В include я включаю другой макет, содержащий FrameLayout и ToolBar. При нажатии пунктов выдвижной панели, а меняю фрагменты в FrameLayout. И вот что мне нужно сделать, нужно чтобы в зависимости от того, какой фрагмент загружен в FrameLayout, менять разметку menu, я про то меню которое создается в методе onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu). Как мне это реализовать, ведь код создания меню же вызывается единожды. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Раз ваше меню зависит от текущего фрагмента, логично и создавать его в методе `onCreateOptionsMenu`, конкретного фрагмента. Чтобы этот метод фрагмента использовался, надо в `onCreate` этого фрагмента вызвать `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`